Common-lisp: Integer is not of type real
I'm confused about how to set a parameter in common lisp, trying to set a global variable for generating a bunch of synth definitions in cl-collider.
This code works:
(defs sine
  :args ((freq 440)
         (lag 0.1))
  :sig ((sig (sin-osc.ar (lag.kr freq lag)))
        (sig (* sig (amp-comp-a.kr freq))))
  :num-channels 2)

but when I do this:
(defparameter *num-channels* 2)
...
:num-channels *num-channels*)

I get this error:
The value
  *NUM-CHANNELS*
is not of type
  REAL
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

The macro that produces the synthdef is this:
(defmacro defs (name &key args sig (num-channels 2) (env :asr) (act :free))
  (let ((pan-func nil)
        (env-func nil)
        (arg-list '((attack 0) (release 0)
                    (out 0) (pan 0) (amp 1))))
    (case num-channels
      ((nil) (setf pan-func 'sig))
      (2 (setf pan-func '(pan2.ar sig pan)))
      (4 (setf pan-func '(pan4.ar sig pan)))
      (t (setf pan-func `(pan-az.ar ,num-channels sig pan :width width))))
    (case env
      (:asr (setf env-func `(env-gen.kr (asr attack 1 release) :gate gate :act ,act)))
      (:perc (setf env-func `(env-gen.kr (perc attack release) :act ,act))))
    (if (not(equal env :perc))
        (setf arg-list (append arg-list '((gate 1)))))
    (if (> num-channels 4)
        (setf arg-list (append arg-list '((width 2)))))
    `(defsynth ,name (,@arg-list ,@args)
       (let* ((env ,env-func)
              ,@sig
              (sig (* sig env amp))
              )
         (out.ar out ,pan-func)))))

Any help much appreciated!

Macros are expanded at compile time. Variables are only available at run time. So you can't pass a variable as an argument to a macro.

defparameter defines the variable at run-time, but you need to get the value when the macro is being expanded by the compiler.
You can use eval-when and read-time evaluation to solve this:
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel)
  (defparameter *num-channels* 2))

(defs sine
  :args ((freq 440)
         (lag 0.1))
  :sig ((sig (sin-osc.ar (lag.kr freq lag)))
        (sig (* sig (amp-comp-a.kr freq))))
  :num-channels #.*num-channels*)


Thanks a lot! This looks a lot better than what I did, but the root problem remains: when I call the macro with ```(defs playbuf-mono
:args ((buf 0) (rate 1) (start-pos 0) (loop 0))
:sig ((sig (play-buf.ar 1
buf rate
:start-pos start-pos
:loop loop)))
:num-channels num-channels)


I just noticed that you have (if (> num-channels 4 (setf arg-list (append arg-list '((width 2))))). If the argument list of the function depends on num-channels, it has to know the value at expansion time.

I've updated the answer to show how to solve this using read-time evaluation.

Oh wow, this is some deep magic. Thanks a lot!

Quick follow-up question: I've looked around the webs, but I can't find any mention of the #. notation. Where could I find more information about this?

@kflak -- check the HyperSpec. The Non-Alphabetic Index is a good resource for things like this.

Awesome, thanks!

First: understand the error message
Your title says: "Integer is not of type real".
That's not the error message. The error message you cite is this:
The value
  *NUM-CHANNELS*
is not of type
  REAL
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

Read carefully. It says "The value *NUM-CHANNELS*...". It does not say "The value of *NUM-CHANNELS* ...".
The error message really means this:
The symbol (!) *num-channels* is not a number of type REAL. That's trivially true, a symbol is not a number.
So your title would need to be something like this:
"a symbol is not of type real".
the actual error
You have code which tries to pass a symbol to a function which expects a real number.
Let's see the difference of a symbol and a number:
CL-USER 12 > (setf *num-channels* 2)
2

CL-USER 13 > (type-of '*num-channels*)
SYMBOL

CL-USER 14 > (type-of *num-channels*)
(UNSIGNED-BYTE 2)

CL-USER 15 > (typep '*num-channels* 'real)
NIL

CL-USER 16 > (typep *num-channels* 'real)
T

Now:
* (+ *num-channels* 1)
3
* (+ '*num-channels* 1)

debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR @700322101C in thread
#<THREAD tid=259 "main thread" RUNNING {7008450353}>:
  The value
    *NUM-CHANNELS*
  is not of type
    NUMBER

As you see, that's a similar error. + expects numbers and one argument was a symbol, not a number.
In the code
Where does the error in your code come from?

The symbol *num-channels** is in (defs sine ... :num-channels num-channels)`.

The local variable num-channels of the macro defs is bound to the symbol *num-channels*.

You later call (> num-channels 4). num-channels value is the symbol *num-channels*. So you try to call > with the symbol *num-channels* and the number 4. > expects its arguments to be numbers of type real. But *num-channels is a symbol and not a number of type real.

ERROR


Typically one also would find out about that, by looking at a backtrace.

Thanks! My confusion is that I can't see where exactly I passed *num-channels* as a symbol, but the debugger don't lie, so I'll keep looking.

You wrote: (defs sine ... :num-channels *num-channels*). It's right there. There is your symbol. The local variable num-channels of the macro defs is bound to the symbol *num-channels*.  You later call (> num-channels 4). num-channels value is the symbol *num-channels*. So you try to call > with the symbol *num-channels* and the number 4. > expects its arguments to be numbers of type real. But *num-channels is a symbol and not a number. -> ERROR

I think Barmar's answer is the most direct answer to the question.  Here are two other approaches which both avoid the read-time eval.
Both of these use a version of defs which is not the same as yours: both of them raise the defaulting of things into the let rather than assigning, and both use channels as the name instead of :num-channels for reasons that will become clear.
The first approach is just to explicitly look up the value.  This uses an auxiliary variable (&aux) to avoid let* or nested lets: either is fine, but I like this:
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defparameter *channels* 2))

(defmacro defs (name &key args sig (channels 2) (env :asr) (act :free)
                     &aux (num-channels (etypecase channels
                                          (integer channels)
                                          (symbol (symbol-value channels)))))
  (let ((pan-func (case num-channels
                     ;; first case can no longer happen, not sure what
                     ;; this should be
                     ((nil) 'sig)
                     (2 '(pan2.ar sig pan))
                     (4 '(pan4.ar sig pan))
                     (otherwise `(pan-az.ar ,num-channels sig pan :width width))))
        (env-func (ecase env
                    (:asr `(env-gen.kr (asr attack 1 release) :gate gate :act ,act))
                    (:perc `(env-gen.kr (perc attack release) :act ,act))))
        (arg-list (append
                   '((attack 0) (release 0)
                     (out 0) (pan 0) (amp 1))
                   (if (not (eq env ':perc))
                       '((gate 1)))
                   (if (> num-channels 4)
                       '((width 2))))))
    `(defsynth ,name (,@arg-list ,@args)
       (let* ((env ,env-func)
              ,@sig
              (sig (* sig env amp)))
         (out.ar out ,pan-func)))))

The second approach is to say: OK, we're now looking up names, why not have an explicit table of names?  Which gives you this:
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defparameter *channel-map*
    '((small 2)
      (big 4))))

(defmacro defs (name &key args sig (channels '2) (env :asr) (act :free)
                     &aux (num-channels (etypecase channels
                                          (integer channels)
                                          (symbol
                                           (let ((v (assoc channels *channel-map*)))
                                             (if v
                                                 (second v)
                                               (error "no entry for ~S" channels)))))))
  (let ((pan-func (case num-channels
                     ;; first case can no longer happen, not sure what
                     ;; this should be
                     ((nil) 'sig)
                     (2 '(pan2.ar sig pan))
                     (4 '(pan4.ar sig pan))
                     (otherwise `(pan-az.ar ,num-channels sig pan :width width))))
        (env-func (ecase env
                    (:asr `(env-gen.kr (asr attack 1 release) :gate gate :act ,act))
                    (:perc `(env-gen.kr (perc attack release) :act ,act))))
        (arg-list (append
                   '((attack 0) (release 0)
                     (out 0) (pan 0) (amp 1))
                   (if (not (eq env ':perc))
                       '((gate 1)))
                   (if (> num-channels 4)
                       '((width 2))))))
    `(defsynth ,name (,@arg-list ,@args)
       (let* ((env ,env-func)
              ,@sig
              (sig (* sig env amp)))
         (out.ar out ,pan-func)))))

So that's two options.

Thanks a lot, very instructive! It'll take me a while to chew through all of that information, though. I'm quite amazed at how complicated the "simple" operation of setting and retrieving an environment variable is in lisp.

The problem is that you're trying to use macros in a weird way: CL makes this possible but it's not going to be easy.

Total cl noob here, so I was expecting that my ways of doing things would be off :-) If you don't mind me asking, what would be a better way to approach this? Is the macro path a good one for this, or are there better ways around it by using functions instead?
